# Azure Function Binder Blob FileName

Tags: azure-functions

I need Azure Blob Filename.
I use Azure Functions with Visual Studio. This is the code:

```
public static async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("containerfromftp/{name}", Connection = "AzureBlobStorage")]Stream imageBlob,
        IBinder binder)
{
   var cloudBlob = await binder.BindAsync<ICloudBlob>(new 
   BlobAttribute("containerfromftp/{name}"));
}
```

I want to user binder to estract information. In IBinder, in private variables, I found what I want.

In the following image the data I'm trying to use.

[Visual Studio Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaiUz.png)

My Bad solution:

```
string blobName = (string)((Binder)binder).BindingData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "name").Value
```

Comment: Why not accept `ICloudBlob` directly as type of `imageBlob`?

Comment: Because I don't want to use function.json file.
ICloudBlob require inout type and must specify it on function.json.

Comment: I would expect SDK to deduct `inout` from type. If it doesn't, I would make an issue on github.

Comment: Another reason to not use ICloudBlob is that sometimes it's preferred to use a BCL type (so that the user code can avoid the direct reference to Blob Storage SDK altogether); and because the other types can be convenient (string will read the contents for you; etc).

Comment: Note that for precompiled case, the 'direction' field in function.json is ignored because it's driven by the SDK attributes directly.  The function.json just has the trigger information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parameter can bind directly to binding data, like so

```
   public static async Task Run(
      [BlobTrigger("containerfromftp/{name}")] Stream imageBlob,
      string  name, // returns the {name} capture 
   )
```